# catch return value after execute external task using launchedTaskWithLaunchPath

Tags: objective-c, macos

I was managed to execute an external task on a different process (child proc) using the method `launchdTaskWithLaunchPath` in the following manner :

```
[[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:path arguments:args] waitUntilExit];
```

However, I'd also like obtain the return value from that specific command. in bash it's saved in the special character `$?`. is there any equivalent in objective C ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:path arguments:args]` returns a `NSTask` object. If you store it in a variable, you can ask for the return value with `myTask.terminationStatus`.

```
NSTask *myTask = [NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:path arguments:args];
[myTask waitUntilExit];
returnValue = myTask.terminationStatus;
```

Comment: thanks man. it really help. perhaps do you know how to do this when the task is executed with privileged elevation using `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges`

Comment: No, I don't. I suggest to ask a new question.